# How to add a value to a key(object) in a dictionary if object has same name (C#)

Tags: c#, dictionary, parameters, key

So, I have a dictionary called Potions. I need to check if a key in potions has the same name as an object passed as an argument. Now I'm able to do that but I can't figure out how to add a value to that particular key if the item object and the key have the same name. This code works fine for the first instance of an object. But when I add another instance object with the same name as a key, I get a key not found exception. I understand that the 2 objects wont be the same.How can I extract the object reference inside the dictionary? Or is there another way?

```
public static void addItem(Potion item)
 {
    if (Potions.Count >0)
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<Potion,int> pair in Potions)
        {
            if (pair.Key.itemName == item.itemName)
            {
            containsItem = true;
            }   
        }
        if (containsItem)
        {
        Potions[item] += 1;
        Debug.Log (Potions[item]);
        containsItem = false;
        }
        else
            {       
            Potions.Add(item,1);
            }
    }
    else
    {
    Potions.Add (item,1);
    }

    foreach(KeyValuePair<Potion,int> pair in Potions)
    {
        Debug.Log (pair.Key.itemName + " : " + pair.Value);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps your `Potion` class should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` (so that potions with equal names are considered to be the same by the dictionary) - or could you just change your dictionary to `<string, int>` where the `string` key is the potion's `itemName`?

Comment: Would your first method work though? Besides the name, the objects won't be the same. I do need the keys to be Potions.

Comment: it would work.. sort of. see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, but that might have other implications. Instead, you can use an `IEqualityComparer` when you create the dictionary, like so:

```
class Potion {
    public string Name;
    public int Color;
}

class PotionNameEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Potion> {
    public bool Equals(Potion p1, Potion p2) {
        return p1.Name.Equals(p2.Name);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Potion p1) {
        return p1.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}

void Main() {
    var d = new Dictionary<Potion, int>(new PotionNameEqualityComparer());
    var p1 = new Potion() { Name = "Health", Color = 1 };
    var p2 = new Potion() { Name = "Health", Color = 2 };
    d.Add(p1, 1);
    d[p2]++; // works, and now you have two health potions. 
             // Of course, the actual instance in the dictionary is p1; 
             // p2 is not stored in the dictionary.    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would actually offer an alternative implementation.

```
enum Potion
{
    Health,
    Mana
}

class PotionBag
{
    readonly int[] _potions = new int[Enum.GetValues(typeof(Potion)).Length];

    public void Add(Potion potion)
    {
        _potions[(int)potion]++;
    }

    public void Use(Potion potion)
    {
        if (GetCount(potion) == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        _potions[(int)potion]--;
    }

    public int GetCount(Potion potion)
    {
        return _potions[(int)potion];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That wont work since you're using the item that you're adding as a key, and it's not the same object.

Why not save the key in a placeholder and then look for it, after the loop?

```
Potion key = null;
foreach(KeyValuePair<Potion,int> pair in Potions)
    {
        if (pair.Key.itemName == item.itemName)
        {
         key = pair.Key
        }   
    }

if(key != null):
    Potions[key] += 1
```

Comment: No, it's a `Dictionary<Potion,int>`, not `Dictionary<string,int>`

Comment: Yeah didn't see that at first, I've changed my answer.

Comment: Pretty sure that will give you a `InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Potion` as the key, but according to your code, what matters to you is `itemName`. So, I'd recommend you to change your dictionary to `<string, int>`. Also, as commented, when using a custom class it's recommend to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Your code could be something like this:

```
 public static void addItem(Potion item)
 {
    if(Potions.ContainsKey(item.itemName))
        Potions[item.itemName] += 1;
    else
        Potions.Add (item.itemName,1);

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string,int> pair in Potions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + " : " + pair.Value);
    }
 }
```

Comment: would the reference still be there if I changed it to string? I'd like to access other parameters from the object's class in the dictionary or otherwise.

Comment: @cookiepuss Yes, the reference is kept. Actually, it's the default comparison as well, but I believe that it would be recommended to override those two methods on your class as well.